# What is EJB Default -[number] in logs?

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb

I am trying to debug our application which is hosted on JBOSS. I see logs like below.

Q: What exactly do `[pool-***]` and `[EJB Default **]` and `[Thread -**]` represent ?
   How it will help me in debugging.

I am a newbie to EJB's , please bear with my ignorance. I could not find good answer in google.

```
2016-08-18 17:55:49,119] [pool-10-thread-1] [DEBUG] com.informatica.mdm.util.SqlHelper: binded stmt: SELECT LAST_CHANGE_DATE FROM C_REPOS_DB_RELEASE
[2016-08-18 17:55:51,132] [pool-10-thread-1] [DEBUG] com.informatica.mdm.util.SqlHelper: binded stmt: SELECT LAST_CHANGE_DATE FROM C_REPOS_DB_RELEASE
[2016-08-18 17:55:51,132] [pool-10-thread-1] [DEBUG] com.informatica.mdm.util.SqlHelper: binded stmt: SELECT LAST_CHANGE_DATE FROM C_REPOS_DB_RELEASE
[2016-08-18 17:55:51,132] [pool-10-thread-1] [DEBUG] com.informatica.mdm.util.SqlHelper: binded stmt: SELECT LAST_CHANGE_DATE FROM C_REPOS_DB_RELEASE
```

or

```
[2016-08-18 17:57:35,448] [Thread-167] [DEBUG] com.siperian.mrm.server.CleanseServerOnlinePollerManager: [com.delos.cmx.server.datalayer.repository.cleanse.ReposCleanseMatchServer@6484aa54]
```

or

```
[2016-08-18 17:56:48,196] [EJB default - 8] [INFO ] com.pfg.idd.customuserexit.util.SIFUtil: PFGCSifUtil - searchQuery - Token Value is :  SVR1.A4BBM and  - MatchCount is : 8
[2016-08-18 17:56:48,196] [EJB default - 8] [INFO ] com.pfg.idd.customuserexit.util.SIFUtil: END of searchQuery method 
[2016-08-18 17:56:48,196] [EJB default - 8] [INFO ] com.pfg.idd.customuserexit.util.VendorUserRole: SearchQueryResponse----->8
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the thread name.  In your example log section there was a single thread running your EJB code.  Ultimately the format of the line is likely derived from a [PattenLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) from log4j.

As to how it will help you - as an example, we can see that the "EJB default - 8" thread ran some code.  I have used it to follow through what a particular thread is doing.